# sapui5 odata value xml content pretty

Tags: for-loop, dynamic, data-binding, sapui5

I have to achive [something like this with multiple types of icons and colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60E8p.png)  so not all the icons in the column should be like that it could be red-icon-status-error or green-icon-status-success in base of oData values.

here is my code:

```
var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                var Source;
                var clr;
                jsonModel.setData(oData);..

for (var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {

            iconSource = oData.results[i].ST;
            switch (iconSource) {
            case 'E':
            {
                Source = "sap-icon://status-error";
                clr = "red";
            }
            break;
            case 'S':
            {
                Source = "sap-icon://status-completed";
                clr = "green";
            }
            break;
            default: 
            {
                Source = "sap-icon://status-critical";
                clr = "grey";
            }
            break;
            }
var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); //set new json model
            jsonModel.setData(oData);//set the json
            var view = that.getView();//get view
            }//i close the for loop
            var exempletable = sap.ui.getCore().byId(view.createId('tableviewid'));
            var statusLabel = new sap.m.Label();
            statusLabel.setText("Stat");
                var statusColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: statusLabel, 
                template: new sap.ui.core.Icon({  
                    src : Source,
                    color : clr
                }),
                width: "40px"
            });
        exempletable.insertColumn(statusColumn, 0);//here insteed of 0 it should be something like 0+i?
        exempletable.setModel(jsonModel);//set model
    exempletable.bindRows("/results");//bind rows
        exempletable.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        exempletable.setEnableSelectAll(false);
            exempletable.setSelectionMode(sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.SingleSelectMaster);   
            exempletable.setNavigationMode(sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Scrollbar);

        });
    },
```

So to reasume how do I loop in order to achive what I want, It's my logic good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new table in the controller you should init the table in the corresponding view. In your table item template you can format the values with a formatter function.

For formatter function example, check out following link:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.23/code

You first do the Model binding in the table and setup the desired property to use the formatter function, the logic of the state handling is defined in the formatter controller (e.g. returns some value for one case).

I'm aussuming you initiallized your model with a given model name and you have knowledge about sapui5 bindings

```
    var oExampleItemTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("idexampletemplate", {
                unread: false,
                cells: [
                    new sap.m.StandardListItem({
// The code after the comma within the title brackets calls the formatter function                      
title: "{parts: [ {path: 'your_model_name>property_name'} ], formatter: '<resourceroot.path.to.formatter.class.convertValueIntoMaterialGroup'}",
                        description: "{your_model_name>property_name}",
                        adaptTitleSize: false,
                        iconInset: true
                    })
    ]
    }),
```

The above code is written for a javascript view, the example for an xml view you can find in the link pasted above.

Best regards